# htaccess Directory and Html file have same name, how can I use modrewrite to point to the Html file?

Tags: file, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have a website where I am using modrewrite the remove the file extension from my html and php pages from the URLs. In doing so, I've made one of my Html files direct to a folder in the same location of the website that shares an exact name with it, so if a user were to type in the url, the site would try to send them to the directory instead of to the Html page. What can I do to make modrewrite direct this to the Html page instead of the directory found in the same location?

I tried using some case sensitive work arounds so I could preserve the wording of both the directory and Html file, but my server had also been set up to be case insensitive so it doesn't work, and I'd prefer to keep it case insensitive anyway.

Comment: You can use a `RewriteCond` to test whether a file with ".html" extension exists, if so rewrite to that, otherwise do whatever you wish. You you implement an exception prior to the more general rules. So something like that: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` . You will find many examples for that here on SO. The first place to look for information about details should be the excellent documentation of the apache module though: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: I had that exact rule already written. The problem is that I have a directory with the same name in the same folder, so when the url is shortened without the .html at the end; it instead tries to access the folder which leads to a forbidden error.

How can I specify in the rewritecond to target the html file and not the folder?

Comment: Please read again before judging. What I wrote is not a _rule_ but a _condition_ . Which controls whether the following rule should get applied or not.

Comment: My apologies for calling that condition a rule; regardless I still had that exact text already written in my htaccess file and it does not help with the problem. 

Keep in mind that I'm trying to differentiate between a file and folder with the same name. Removing the .html extension from the webpage causes the browser to try to redirect to the folder which gives the forbidden error. I've read through the documentation and read your comment multiple times before posting, but I have yet to find a solution to the issue I am having.

Comment: I will add a short answer to avoid miss understandings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments to what I suggested in the comments to the question above I assume your issue is caused by other rewriting rules you have in place. Keep in mind, that the order of rules is very important!

I do not know your exact situation and you did not post your current implementation. So I have to guess a bit, you certainly will have to modify the following:

```
MultiViews off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded and activated for this. Any you need to have allowed overriding (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation).